# Can't access a pod from another pod using NodePort service

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a very simple setup. I'm running Kubernetes using the Docker Desktop Kubernetes feature on my PC.

1. There are 2 pods running from the yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: my-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
```

1. There is another pod running from the command: `kubectl run nginx-standalone --image nginx:alpine`
2. There is a service from yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: nginx-nodeport
spec:
 type: NodePort
 selector:
    app: my-nginx
 ports:
 - port: 80
   targetPort: 80
   nodePort: 31000
```

Basically, the service is "connected" only to the pods that come from yaml deployment, due to labels selector.

What I'm doing:

1. I "ssh" into nginx-standalone
2. I installed curl (inside  of nginx-standalone)
3. I tried the following (inside  of nginx-standalone):

   1. `curl nginx-nodeport` - works well, I get the proper response
   2. `curl nginx-nodeport:31000` - does not work, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to nginx-nodeport port 31000: Connection refused`

I do not understand why the 2nd command does not return a successful HTTP response. I know that the `31000` port works, because I can do `curl nginx-nodeport:31000` from my host PC. Why it does not work from the nginx-standalone pod?

Comment: OS ? ubuntu ? redhat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected behavior because the `nodePort` `31000` is listening on the nodes network interface and does not exist in pod's network interface. If you want to access a pod from another pod via kubernetes service use `clusterIP` type service instead of `NodePort` type. `NodePort` type service should be used for exposing a kubernetes pod to consumers outside the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: You can reach a NodePort or LoadBalancer service from within the cluster, but you need to use the cluster-internal `port:`.

Comment: These NodePort questions keep coming up over and over again, we can re-use existing answers and on my opinion, the community should focus on re-using answers and focus on answering the new types of questions.